# How can remove installed package from virtual environment directory?

Tags: python, package, virtualenv, uninstallation

I have install `orjson` package this way:

```
python -m  pip install  --target=/home/debian/hm/lib/python3.9/site-packages  orjson
```

If i don't use the `--target` argument,`orjson` will be installed in `/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.
The app requires orjson==3.8.1, but i have orjson 3.9.2 which is incompatible.
So i want to uninstall it:

```
python -m  pip uninstall  orjson
Found existing installation: orjson 3.8.1
Not uninstalling orjson at /home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages, outside environment /home/debian/hm
Can't uninstall 'orjson'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Another try:

```
python -m  pip uninstall  --target=/home/debian/hm/lib/python3.9/site-packages   orjson

Usage:   
  /home/debian/hm/bin/python -m pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  /home/debian/hm/bin/python -m pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: --target
```

It can be deleted with:

```
rm -rf   /home/debian/hm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/orjson*
```

I dislike that.